# Media 7.0-2.x and Plupload

Tags: 7, media, files

Is there any combination of Media module in version 2.x for Drupal 7 which works with Plupload Integration of any version?

I installed the newest `dev` versions of `File entity`, `Media` and `Plupload` but they don't work togheter.

Is there any other Bulk upload for Media which already works with version 2.x?

Are there any patches I can apply to get Media togheter with Plupload working?

Comment: Hey there. I struggled with that combo for awhile, but started to phase it out when it became too troublesome to maintain. With Media 7.x-2.0-unstable7 I had to add the [Multiple Forms](http://drupal.org/project/multiform) module and (if I recall correctly) [Media Multiselect](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/fangel/1652676) to keep bulk uploads working at the time. I do keep copious notes so let me know if there is more I can tell you.

Comment: @othermachines Thx a lot :-). Installation of the missing `Media Multiselect` module helped out. Although I had to apply [the following patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2216273#comment-9642477) to the current master commit to get it working with the newest dev versions of Media and Plupload Integration. Now it seems to work fine if I change the Widget type for my `File` field. You may create an answer for my question and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Hey, that's really great. Glad you got it sorted. I've posted my suggestion as an answer, with an added note about the patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a little while for me and it was tricky at the time, but enabling these modules should help:

- [Multiple Forms](http://drupal.org/project/multiform)
- [Media Multiselect](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/fangel/1652676) (provides a "Media Multiselect" widget instead of the standard *Media Browser*)

There was an additional patch to Media and a plethora of other issues (mostly related to permissions and editing files) that I noted as resolved as of 2014-Sep.

As you point out in the comments, a patch to the Media Multiselect module was still required to get the most recent dev versions of Plupload and Media 2.x working together by changing the widget type to that provided by Media Multiselect:

Patch (required for now but under review): [Issue #2216273: Latest media changes break the multiselect (Comment #52)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2216273#comment-9642477)

Cheers -

Answer (score 0):

maybe the [file field sources](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) module works with media - i did not check yet.

Answer (score 0):

For the media module, I believe the issue to follow is https://www.drupal.org/node/951004